# Allow backorders and notify customer for specific product categories in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, stock

IN woocommerce I'm trying to add some code in `functions.php` to allow backorder for specific product categories. But the code doesn't works.

How can I allow backorders and notify customer for specific product categories in Woocommerce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated**

Try the following *(where you will set your product category(ies) in the array for each function)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_is_in_stock', 'filter_product_is_in_stock', 10, 2 );
function filter_product_is_in_stock( $is_in_stock, $product ){
    // Here set the products categories in the array (can be terms ids, slugs or names)
    $categories = array("clothing");

    if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ){
        $is_in_stock = true;
    }
    return $is_in_stock;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_backorders_allowed', 'filter_products_backorders_allowed', 10, 3 );
function filter_products_backorders_allowed( $backorder_allowed, $product_id, $product ){
    // Here set the products categories in the array (can be terms ids, slugs or names)
    $categories = array("clothing");

    if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ){
        $backorder_allowed = true;
    }
    return $backorder_allowed;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_backorders_require_notification', 'filter_product_backorders_require_notification', 10, 2 );
function filter_product_backorders_require_notification( $notify, $product ){
    // Here set the products categories in the array (can be terms ids, slugs or names)
    $categories = array("clothing");

    if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ){
        $notify = true;
    }
    return $notify;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

[image]

> For parent product categories: 
>   [Allow backorders and notify customer for parent product categories in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52564637/using-root-categories-in-global-backorder-function/52564958#52564958)

Comment: I've tried the code in function.php but some error occured sir.
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare filter_products_backorders_allowed() (previously declared in /home1/digitsor/public_html/wp-content/themes/dokan/functions.php:369) in /home1/digitsor/public_html/wp-content/themes/dokan/functions.php on line 388

Comment: thanks for the reply sir, I've tried it. I placed the two categories in allow backorder and with notification but nothing happens.

Comment: @ErwinManalang I have added some more code, tested and now it works perfectly… If it works for you you could please accept the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Its working now. I have one last question sir, the code seems to be working on subcategories only.How can i add root or parent category and multiply categories in array? sorry for newbie question.

Comment: Sir please help regarding to the root categories to work with the code. thanks sir