# Allow backorders and notify customer for parent product categories in Woocommerce Bug with Variable products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I'm using this code to enable backorders in products for all categories: 
[Allow backorders and notify customer for parent product categories in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52564637/allow-backorders-and-notify-customer-for-parent-product-categories-in-woocommerc/52564958#52564958)

it works well, but when I add this code which adds the stocks of all variant in variable products [Display the stock availability for all product types in Woocommerce archive pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53235951/display-the-stock-availability-for-all-product-types-in-woocommerce-archive-page/53238468#53238468), the problem occurs. Both code works well when they are not combined in the function together.

[image]

The backorder note doesn't show in the variable products. and the icons in my homepage seems to become large. (see the picture below.)

[image]

Comment: I have updated the code from [Allow backorders and notify customer for parent product categories in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52564637/allow-backorders-and-notify-customer-for-parent-product-categories-in-woocommerc/52564958#52564958) … There was a bug.

Comment: i've tried the edited code sir. All of the products under the targeted categories  works well, except in cellphones which has a a variable product.

Comment: I have tested everything and for me it works… I will look tomorrow to see if I catch something wrong. Try to enable debug in `wp-config.php` file  changing `define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );` to `true` and adding `define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );` and `define( 'WC_TEMPLATE_DEBUG_MODE', true );` to see if you get some error messages… Then message me.

Comment: ok sir I'll try to debug it. thanks for info :)